# Passing bit-by-bit encryption via pipes to output file

Tags: c, file, encryption, pipe, buffer

My XOR encryption has been working via 2 child processes before I introduced a shared pipe. Once I introduced a shared pipe, I found that:

1. Both child processes do run
2. Bit-by-bit encryption does run with the 'encryptFile' process running correctly
3. The 'test' string is never printed in the 'writeToOutFile' function, indicating the while loop is never called.

Is this error being caused by the way I pass/handle pipes, or is it due to an incorrect statement of the read function?

I have included all the code.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
...



void encrypt(....){

    while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) { 
        ....
        }
        char x = ...;
        write(fd, &x, 1); 

    }

close(fd);

}


void writeOut(...){

char outchar;

while(read(fd, &outchar, 1) > 0){ 
    ...
}
close(fd);
}


int main(...]){

    int fd[2];

    pipe(fd);

    pid_t ....;
    FILE ....;


...

      child_a = fork();

      if (child_a == 0) {
           //Child A code
                 close(fd[0]);
                 encrypt(in, fd[1], k, c); //for using write end


      } else {
          child_b = fork();

          if (child_b == 0) {
               //Child B code
                         close(fd[1]);
                         writeOut(out, fd[0]); 


          } else {
              //Parent Code
              waitpid(child_a,NULL,0);
                waitpid(child_b,NULL,0);
                        close(fd[1]);
                        close(fd[0]);
          }
      }

    }
```

Comment: I think we need to see more code, to see how you're calling the two functions. But you should be able to debug this with your debugger, and see where things are getting stuck.

Comment: @Barmar I put in the full code, it's based on a question you answered a while back

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple typo:

```
while(read(pipe1, &outchar, 1) < 0)
```

should be:

```
while(read(pipe1, &outchar, 1) > 0)
```

`read()` returns the number of characters that were read, `0` at EOF, or `-1` when there's an error. So your loop stops immediately unless it reads EOF immediately from the pipe or gets an error.

Another problem is that you need to close the pipe FDs that aren't being used in each process. The read end of the pipe doesn't return EOF until *all* processes that have the write end close it. So in the branch marked `//Child A code` add:

```
close(pipe1[0]);
```

and in the branch marked `//Child B code` add:

```
close(pipe1[1]));
```

and do both in the `//Parent code` branch before calling `waitpid()`.